# Closed form for this 2 variable recurrence?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form for this two variable recurrence, but Wolfram Alpha does not seem to understand the input.

$$
\begin{cases}
a_{0,1} = 1  \\
a_{0,i} = 0 \quad \forall i\neq1 \\
a_{j,k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{i}{k-i} \cdot a_{(j-1),i} 
\end{cases}
$$

with the convention that 
$$\binom{x}{y}=0 \quad \forall y \gt x $$

The problem arises from a combinatorial sequence; I'm trying to get the closed form to calculate the sequence terms quickly.

Comment: $a_{0,i}$ contradicts $a_{0,1}$?

Comment: Was missing the i<>1. Corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for $a_{j,j}$ are $0$. Values for $a_{j, j+1}$ are factorials $j!$, but I don't have a good idea for the others.

[image]
[image]

The table was generated by a home-made `C#` program making use of the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` library in *Microsoft .Net*

Comment: How did you get the table up to 12 ? I wrote a program, but the numbers gets too big quickly. Would it be possible to expand it in the k direction ? I'm interested in the sum of all nonzero terms for each k.

Comment: Looks like the sums are [OEIS A171792](https://oeis.org/A171792).